# jQuery UI sortable revert option - enable dragging during animation

Tags: jquery-ui, animation, jquery-ui-sortable, revert

I currently have a jQuery UI sortable element and I set the `revert` option to `1000` for a smooth but not too fast animation. While the animation works fine, it seems like I cannot drag during the animation.

I made a simplified version on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bA7Dk/. When dragging the `1` somewhere and releasing the mouse, it isn't until the animation has completed that you can drag the `2`.

Is there any way to enable dragging during the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out by altering `jquery.ui.sortable.js`:

- Add this as an property to `$.widget` (where all functions are added as well):

  ```
  revertingElem: $(),
  ```
- Modify inside `_mouseStop`:

  ```
  self.reverting = true
  ```

  to

  ```
  self.reverting = true           
  this.revertingElem = $(this.helper);
  ```
- Modify inside `_mouseCapture`:

  ```
  return false;     (the first occurence)
  ```

  to

  ```
  $(this.revertingElem).stop(true, true);
  ```